# Changing the formatting of clicked text in a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, click, format, textblock

I have a textBlock to which I've added some text e.g. as follows:

```
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run("One "));
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run("Two "));
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run("Three "));
```

How can I add a click event that changes the color of the text of the inline that has been clicked?

e.g. if "One" is clicked I'd like it to have a red font; then if "Two" is clicked, I'd like "One" to be black again, and "Two" to be red, so that the color of the last word clicked is red.

I'm fairly new to programming with c# and wpf.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What for a textBlock ? Maibe TextBox ?

Comment: As I understand it, I have more control over formatting the text with different styles with a textBlock and I don't need the text to be selectable or editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
     public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run("One "));
        textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run("Two "));
        textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run("Three "));
    }

    private SolidColorBrush _blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    private SolidColorBrush _redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    private Run _selectedRun;

    private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var run = e.OriginalSource as Run;
        if (run != null)
        {
            if (_selectedRun != null)
            {
                _selectedRun.Foreground = _blackBrush;
                if (_selectedRun == run)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            run.Foreground = _redBrush;
            _selectedRun = run;
        }
    }
```

But you will have to handle click with "MouseDown" or "MouseUp" as Textblock does not have Click event

To color one at a certain index this is a quick example.

```
private void ColorInlineAtIndex(InlineCollection inlines, int index, Brush brush)
{
    if (index <= inlines.Count - 1)
    {
          inlines.ElementAt(index).Foreground = brush;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 ColorInlineAtIndex(textBlock1.Inlines, 2, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
```

Find position:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var run = e.OriginalSource as Run;
    if (run != null)
    {
        int position = (sender as TextBlock).Inlines.ToList().IndexOf(run);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited answer to add complete example

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly and is very useful for pointing me in the right direction! If I may ask 2 further related questions here, if my textblock had many more inlines, 1.) how could I make the text red for a specified inline e.g. the tenth (or any other number) e.g. if I wanted to make the tenth word red? 2.) Conversely, when an inline is clicked, how can I know what the position of that inline in the textblock inlines collection is i.e. is it the tenth or the forty-first inline that has been clicked?

Comment: Thanks for your help, sa_ddam213! :)